# react native :there is way to view the data that coming from state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm trying to view all the data in the "swiper" coming from state but for some reason I can't see.
I'd love some help because i dont undrstand whats wrong there .
I go through the data with the map function and it doesn't work.
The goal is to display a table with the data

[this is the link picture for how it should display :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxXLf.jpg)

```
export default class InfoTable extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tableHead0: [`${this.props.headerInfo.SHORT_TEXT} (${(this.props.headerInfo.ORDERID).replace(/^0+/, '')})`],
            tableHead3: ['BANANA'],
            tableData3: [
                ['APPLE', `${this.props.headerInfo.COSTCENTER_TXT} (${(this.props.headerInfo.COSTCENTER)})`],
                ['MONKEY', `${this.props.headerInfo.LOC_WBS_ELEM_TXT} (${this.props.headerInfo.LOC_WBS_ELEM})`],
                ['FRIZ', `${this.props.headerInfo.SETTLORDER_TXT} (${this.props.headerInfo.SETTLORDER})`],
            ]
        }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.headerInfo != null) {
            this.setState({ tableHead0: [nextProps.headerInfo] })
        }
        alert(JSON.stringify(nextProps))
    }

    render() {
        const state = this.state;
        return (
            <Swiper style={styles.wrapper} showsButtons={true}>
                <ScrollView>
                    <View style={styles.container}>
                        <Table borderStyle={{ borderWidth: 2, borderColor: '#d83dff' }}>
                            <Row data={state.tableHead0} style={styles.head0} textStyle={styles.headText} />
                            <Row data={state.tableHead1} style={styles.head} textStyle={styles.headText} />
                            <Rows data={state.tableData1} textStyle={styles.text} />
                            <Row data={state.tableHead2} style={styles.head} textStyle={styles.headText} />
                            <Rows data={state.tableData2} textStyle={styles.text} />
                            <Row data={state.tableHead3} style={styles.head} textStyle={styles.headText} />
                            <Rows data={state.tableData3} textStyle={styles.text} />
                        </Table>
                    </View>
                </ScrollView>
            </Swiper>
        )
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: { flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff' },
    head0: { height: 80, backgroundColor: '#54beff' },
    head: { height: 40, backgroundColor: '#9febf5' },
    headText: { fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 20 },
    text: { margin: 10 },
});
```

Comment: which Library u are using for swiper, use log to check what props are u getting

Comment: this is the link :
[link](https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper)

Comment: use console.log(this.props) before before setting state and check what data are ugetting

Comment: I change the code above to my initial code :
the initial situation from which I want to present my data
How do I loop the data and then display it in a swiper?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question! Are you looking to swipe through the different versions of `tableHeadN` and `tableDataN` that you have?

Comment: That's right!
But everything about quotas isn't supposed to change because it's as static as the banana and the apple and the monkey and friz
only all the "this.props.headerInfo." Are supposed to change

Answer (score 0):

Hey there you can use [Flatlist](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist), in which all the data will be passed as an array and it will show all your data it will help you.

```
 import {Flatlist} from react-native;
    export default class InfoTable extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                tableHead0: [`${this.props.headerInfo.SHORT_TEXT} (${(this.props.headerInfo.ORDERID).replace(/^0+/, '')})`],
                tableHead3: ['BANANA'],
                tableData3: [
                    ['APPLE', `${this.props.headerInfo.COSTCENTER_TXT} (${(this.props.headerInfo.COSTCENTER)})`],
                    ['MONKEY', `${this.props.headerInfo.LOC_WBS_ELEM_TXT} (${this.props.headerInfo.LOC_WBS_ELEM})`],
                    ['FRIZ', `${this.props.headerInfo.SETTLORDER_TXT} (${this.props.headerInfo.SETTLORDER})`],
                ]
            }
        }

        componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
            if (nextProps.headerInfo != null) {
                this.setState({ tableHead0: [nextProps.headerInfo] })
            }
            alert(JSON.stringify(nextProps))
        }

        render() {
            const state = this.state;
            return (
             <View style={styles.container}>
                            <FlatList
                //pass your state in data
                data={this.state.tableData3}
                renderItem={({ item }) =>
                 <View>
                    <Text>{item}</Text>
                    //this render item render the data so you can show data as you 
                    want to.
                 </View>
                 }
                keyExtractor={item => item.id}
              />
                        </View>
            )
        }
    }
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: { flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff' },
        head0: { height: 80, backgroundColor: '#54beff' },
        head: { height: 40, backgroundColor: '#9febf5' },
        headText: { fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 20 },
        text: { margin: 10 },
    });
```

the `item` in `render item` contain all the data and print it, weather it contain 100 of item it will print it in a list and you can scroll it , Flatlist is used with array data only.

Hope it helps, feel free for Doubts.

Comment: i am new in react native, could you please write me all your solution with my code above ?

Comment: I updated the updated answer, please check it and do upvote.

Comment: i dont understand where is all the part of the "Swiper" ? can you show me the exactly my code with your solution ? because all the part of the Swiper is missing and its confuse me

Comment: there is no swiper as flatlist will automatically create swiper as its own

Comment: added a link in my flatlist keyword , check there how it works

Comment: but i need all this :
`
<ScrollView>
                    <View style={styles.container}>
                        <Table borderStyle={{ borderWidth: 2, borderColor: '#d83dff' }}>
                            <Row data={state.tableHead0} style={styles.head0} textStyle={styles.headText} />
     </Table>
                    </View>
                </ScrollView>
`

Comment: Then render table component in flatlist , it will show all the array data in your table

Comment: Can you show me how to do it ?
The goal is that I can browse the tables and see different data between table and table

Comment: yes sure I will , but can you show me how you want to show data? any layouts?

Comment: i add a link picture for how i want the data, its need to be swipe to the sides and shuold show me all the data from the json .